# use spdlog accross packages using or not ROS2

Tags: ros2, logger

we are looking for a logging solution that is going to be long term supported and that is, as a bonus, compatible with ROS2.

I would like to know is this is possible to:

1. Create a package using spdlog
2. Create ros package wrapping up the first one.
3. Forward the logs from the 1rst package the second one so all logs appear in the ROS::logger at the end.

Do you think it's feasible?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

spdlog is already used in ROS 2 for logging under the hood, see [here](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/a/97124/33077). So the long-term support is there as long as someone maintains it (if the [default backend is changed](https://github.com/ros2/rcl_logging) over time).

If I understood you correctly, you want to use spdlog in an project that does not need ROS 2 and then create wrapper around it to create a ROS 2 package. Now when you use the ROS 2 package, all logs (defined via `spdlog::debug/SPDLOG_DEBUG` from the underlying project or `RCLCPP_DEBUG` from the ROS 2 wrapper) should appear as they would if all logs were created in a ROS 2 style.
According to the [Logging and logger configuration concept](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Concepts/Intermediate/About-Logging.html) it is not so easy because logging involves several "stages" (subsystem of different libraries). You will probably have to redirect your spdlog log message through the rcl so that it is treated as a ROS 2 log message (publishing via console, file and network).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will try to investigate further these concepts.

Answer (score 1):

**Q1 and Q2:**

Yes.

Have a look at the [`rcl_logging_spdlog` package](https://github.com/ros2/rcl_logging/tree/rolling/rcl_logging_spdlog) (which implements the [`rcl_logging_interface`](https://github.com/ros2/rcl_logging/tree/rolling/rcl_logging_interface)  using `spdlog`).

If you check its `CMakeLists.txt`, you will see how it [finds `spdlog`](https://github.com/ros2/rcl_logging/blob/014239dd80ab3de2a847af80f23d24da6438ecb7/rcl_logging_spdlog/CMakeLists.txt#L19-L20) and how it [links with `spdlog`](https://github.com/ros2/rcl_logging/blob/014239dd80ab3de2a847af80f23d24da6438ecb7/rcl_logging_spdlog/CMakeLists.txt#L33-L36).

**Q3:**

Not just like that.

The ROS `spdlog` backend opens a logfile (per process!) and writes log messages to it, but there is no support to send extra log messages from some other source to that same log file.

Some possible ideas:

- Write your own implementation of the `rcl_logging_interface` with the same functionality as the default `rcl_logging_spdlog` package, but which has extra functionality to receive the extra log messages and write them to that file,
- Use the `/rosout` log output instead, publish the extra log messages to that same topic and have a listener write that output to a file (I think you can use [`ros2 bag`](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/Tutorials/Beginner-CLI-Tools/Recording-And-Playing-Back-Data/Recording-And-Playing-Back-Data.html) for that).

**General:**

For a code walkthrough wrt. the `rclcpp` logging system, see [here](https://github.com/jrutgeer/ROS2_assorted_docs/blob/main/ROS2_core/ROS2_logging.md).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response! this much appreciated!
It seems spdlog is at least supported for now. And may seem a good fit for us.